# Avoid keycode check on each keydown event

Tags: javascript, forms, iframe

I have a form inside iframe (id:iframeId).I cannot change the content of the form anyway. 
Now, the form should not be submitted on hitting `enter` (keyCode 13) since there is some customization (field value modification etc.) being done.
The below script is what being used to prevent form from submitting on hitting `enter` key. But this is being triggered on every key press and hence degrading the user experience while entering data into the form.

```
$(document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.document).keydown(function (e) {
        if(e.keyCode==13)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Form is not getting submitted");
        }
    });
```

Can someone suggest a better way to implement the same i.e. prevent form (inside iframe) from submitting on hitting `enter` button?

Comment: *"But this is being triggered on every key press and hence degrading the user experience while entering data into the form."* The only reason this would degrade the user experience is the `alert`. Simply remove it. Having a handler called on every keydown isn't something a user will know about otherwise.

Comment: Okay...that alert is just for testing/debugging purpose. Keeping that aside there is a condition check on every keydown event. Is it really fine?

Comment: Of course it is, that check is executed in **well** under a millisecond, even on a slow mobile device. Something has to take roughly 50-100ms for a human to notice it.